# Null pointer exception while doing AsyncTask Android

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask

i'm trying to populate a gridlayout through json loading from a website, it must show the image, the name and a link when clicking on it.

When trying to populate with asynctask i get the following error:

```
03-14 15:02:11.053: E/AndroidRuntime(10155): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 15:02:11.053: E/AndroidRuntime(10155): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 15:02:11.053: E/AndroidRuntime(10155):    at com.videotrafico.MainActivity$DownloadCAMARAS.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:515)
03-14 15:02:11.053: E/AndroidRuntime(10155):    at com.videotrafico.MainActivity$DownloadCAMARAS.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
03-14 15:02:11.053: E/AndroidRuntime(10155):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-14 15:02:11.053: E/AndroidRuntime(10155):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-14 15:02:11.053: E/AndroidRuntime(10155):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-14 15:02:11.053: E/AndroidRuntime(10155):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 15:02:11.053: E/AndroidRuntime(10155):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-14 15:02:11.053: E/AndroidRuntime(10155):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
03-14 15:02:11.053: E/AndroidRuntime(10155):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 15:02:11.053: E/AndroidRuntime(10155):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 15:02:11.053: E/AndroidRuntime(10155):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
03-14 15:02:11.053: E/AndroidRuntime(10155):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
03-14 15:02:11.053: E/AndroidRuntime(10155):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I saw the output of the webpage and is ok.

This is my code:

```
public class DownloadCAMARAS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Cargando cámaras, esto puede tomar hasta 20 segundos dependiendo de su conexión.");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://www.videotrafico.com/api/camaras.php");

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("datos");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject  = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put("imagen", jsonobject.getString("imagen"));
                map.put("nombrecam", jsonobject.getString("nombrecam"));
                map.put("enlace", jsonobject.getString("enlace"));
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {


        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridcams);

        adapter2 = new ListViewAdapter2(MainActivity.this, arraylist);

        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter2);

        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Now it gives me this problem:

I'm using android support library v7:

```
03-14 15:43:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(11642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 15:43:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(11642): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridView
03-14 15:43:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at com.videotrafico.MainActivity$DownloadCAMARAS.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:510)
03-14 15:43:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at com.videotrafico.MainActivity$DownloadCAMARAS.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
03-14 15:43:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-14 15:43:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-14 15:43:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-14 15:43:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 15:43:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-14 15:43:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
03-14 15:43:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 15:43:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 15:43:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
03-14 15:43:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
03-14 15:43:03.039: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: in line 515 is this: gridview.setAdapter(adapter2);

Comment: Its something in your onPostExecute, its probably that your gridView is null when you are trying to set the adapter on it. Or your progressDialog is null and you are trying to dismiss it.

Comment: Yup, thanks it was the layouts, but now i have another problem :P i've updated the OP. Please check it.

Comment: You're trying to cast a GridLayout to a GridView. Either change your GridView in your activity to a GridLayout or change your GridLayout in the R.id.gridcams xml to a GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd problem is that here:

```
 gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridcams);
```

the view `findViewById(R.id.gridcams)` returned seemed to be a `GridLayout` instead of a `GridView`.

==> ClassCastException

**Solution:** Change the view with the id `R.id.gridcams` to be a GridView in your layout, so that findViewById returns a GridView.